# c# Geting previous/next text of a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I have a combobox with a datasource of an excel file [ID];[NAME], but I need to get the previous or next item of the selected item.
Ex:

```
ID   NAME
1    Name1
2    Name2
3    Name3
```

For instance if my selectedindex is 2 - Name2 I need to be able to get the previous item.... 1 - Name1

I've already tried to use cmbNames.Items[cmbNames.selectedindex - 1] but notting... is there a way of gething the displaymenter of an item that is not selected?

Comment: `cmbNames.Items[cmbNames.SelectedIndex - 1]` should work as long as the selected index is not 0 in which case you will get an error. If I remember right, `Items` is a collection of objects, so you might have to use a `cmbNames.Items[cmbNames.SelectedIndex - 1].ToString()` if you want the string value.

Answer (score 1):

i have a example for you, it might help:
(you can get the value you want through the event)

```
private ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();

public Form1(){
    cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += cmb_SelectedIndexChanged;
    var randomList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    cmb.DataSource = randomList;
}

void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var current = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;

        var before = cmb.Items[current - 1];
        MessageBox.Show(before.ToString());

        var after = cmb.Items[current + 1];
        MessageBox.Show(after.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I'm trying your code but it appears the before as object, if I created a messagebox.show(before.ToString()) it appears System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Resolved! Thanks Mohamed. I've used (current as DataRowView).Row[1].ToString() and give me the string.... Thanks again.